# Can I instantly forward a port-range with UPnP?

Tags: c#, com, upnp, portforwarding

I am currently using the COM object "`Interop.NATUPNPLib`" in order to port-forward a couple of ports using UPnP.

I can forward ports individually just fine, but now I have a port range that I want to add (say 8463 through 8467), but all that this COM library is letting me do is add single ports in the form of integers.

How am I to forward an entire range? Will I have to add every port in the specified range individually, or is there another solution?

Comment: We'll need more information. How are you expecting to be able to configure your port ranges?

Comment: Isn't that what I am asking? I need to configure something like port range 8463 - 8467, so I'm asking wether there is a way to tell UPnP to forward that entire range, or if I have to add every port in that range (8463, 8464, 8465, ...) individually.

Comment: My question is more based around how you plan to allow the user to specify port range (hard-coded meaning not at all, semi-interactively through app/web.config, or completely interactively through some sort of UI). I only ask because it would be possible to do the looping in your code to allow this functionality (perhaps through an extension method).

Comment: I am using a WPF application with a UI where the user can specify the ports. My idea is that a user would be able to enter "8463-8467" as a port in the text box, and that it would then forward that range.

Comment: Ok so simple enough, parse the port range string and force the iteration.

Comment: Right, but I was asking if it was possible to simply send a range through to UPnP, instead of single ports. Thanks though.

Comment: The API doesn't appear to support this based on what I could find. I've never used this myself though so I'm not sure if I've missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the UPNP / IGD spec here http://upnp.org/specs/gw/igd2/ I'm not seeing a way to add port ranges in the spec.  There is an option to remove mappings by range, but I only see commands to add mappings one at a time.  If I'm reading the spec correctly, and some library out there does allow for port ranges, then it must be looping through and adding them one at a time behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: Thanks, very informative! Should've looked at the standards. Good thinking.